# how can select relationship data in laravel while cout and group by

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

here is my tables

[Points table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGx34.png)

[Account table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNiJG.png)

[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntIQK.png)

while i get sum(value) and group them by battlepointable_id same time i need some other information from account and user table 
how ca i get them in laravel

Comment: Hi Rahel, you need to try give some more detail, its unlikely people will help if you post images instead of code samples.  What you need is Relationships, check out the Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Comment: This is more an SQL question. Make you can use subselects. Define the query on the points table including the group by, use that as a subselect, joining the other tables you need. `select * from (select ... ) subselect join other on subselect.id = other.id`. You can use the parcel query builder for this.